# How to implement two views in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to implement two views in an Activity?

1.Click the left view can change the right and the right view can slide.
2.Two views can click.

These images from Flyme OS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ...What is the question?

Comment: use fragment. you can set 2 layout in one activity. btw you can choose navigation drawer template in android studio to start your project

Comment: When I use two fragments in an Activity, How can I implement the right view slide animation?

Comment: You can able to assign an animation to any View.same like you can assign the animation to fragments too.